# What is `this` inside Number/ String Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

So I'm extending some native JS objects and noticed some oddities when it comes to `this`.  When I log `this` on strings, I notice it's an array-like object which also has a property called `[[PrimitiveValue]]` which contains the value the value I'd expect, but cannot be retrieved using a `obj['[[PrimitiveValue]]']` syntax.

Take this example:

```
String.prototype.method = function() {
  return this;
};

Number.prototype.method = function() {
  return this;
};

var str = "12";
var num = 12;

console.log( str.method() );
console.log( num.method() );
```

Wanting to get the actual value, I tried something like this however it gets logged as undefined:

```
String.prototype.method = function() {
  return this['[[PrimitiveValue]]'];
};

Number.prototype.method = function() {
  return this['[[PrimitiveValue]]'];
};
```

I noticed it was possible to get the raw value using some type conversion, however this feels really hackish.  (`this + 0` for Number, `this + ''` for String.)

So what type of object am I dealing with here?  How do I effectively interact with `this` inside a native JS object's prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just the native objects; you use `this` just like in a normal prototype function.

Note that you are indeed working with objects: instances built with the "String" or "Number" or some other native constructor. Things like `"hello world"` and `12.54` are not objects, they're primitives. They don't have prototypes.

When you use a primitive object as if it were an object, the runtime automatically promotes it to an object instance. That happens when you use a primitive value with the `.` or `[]` operators.

From such objects (instances of String, Number, or Boolean), the primitive value can be fetched with `this.valueOf()`.

Comment: Interesting, never knew about `.valueOf()`.  Do you know of any places I could go to read up on the details?

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

Comment: Fwiw, I may be wrong, but I think in strict mode, `this` will even refer to the primitive value.

Comment: @FelixKling Confirming that when in `use strict` mode `this` refers to the value of the JS primitive.

Comment: Ah well that makes sense; I didn't even think of that :)  Those standards guys are always thinking about us little people

Answer (score 2):

In the String prototype, `this` refers to String object type. It has the length property, but it is not a real array, it an is array-like object. You can access the `this` value at subscripts like `this[0]` an so forth, but to convert it an array so you can use methods such as [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and all the other prototype methods of the Array, you may do `var args = Array.prototype.call(this);` For example let's illustrate this:

```
String.prototype.hello = function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(typeof this);
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));    
}
"adfadfda".hello();
```

To get the full string as called on the hello method, you can use `this.toString();` which would return in this case `"adfadfda"`

[image]

To actually see the type of object that the `this` value represents we can do:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(this);
```

Which would return:

```
[object String]
```

Comment: In functions defined on the String prototype, when called via String instances, `this` refers to a String instance. String instances are **not** arrays of characters; they're String instances (objects). The primitive string value of a String instance can be obtained with the `.toString()` function.

Comment: I can tell it's not an actual array (`Array.isArray` comes back false).  I'm more interested in how to correctly interact with the `this` object.  @Pointy mentioned `.valueOf()`, which might just be the ticket for what I need.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica yes `.valueOf()` gets you the primitive value around which the object instance was instantiated.

Comment: If you know of any resources on how the native prototypes work, I'd be super interested in learning more.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica they work just like any other prototype. The magic comes in when *native* values - non-objects like string or numeric constants - are auto-boxed in object instances. So, `"hello world".length` implicitly creates a String instance behind the scenes.

Comment: *"this refers to an special data type that acts like an arguments data type"* not really, `this` is of the data type "object" and in particular it is a String object.

Comment: @Felix Kling You're absolutely right. I've validated your statement by checking the type of object that the `this` value represents and I've edited my answer to reflect that.